# Are methods defined in helper directory accesible in controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

in the following code the method `log_in` is defined in **app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb**. The code is from railstutorial.org. I just wanted to know if the methods defined in helpers are available to contollers(non-corresponding controllers). And if they are available how are they available.

The following code is from app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def create
 @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
   log_in @user
   flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
   redirect_to @user
  else
   render 'new'
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right I got this one - we need include sessions_helper in the application controller to make helpers available to controller.